# Send form (PHP) data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to send a form data with Ajax after validation

About validation all think that's work

but about send data I have some problems

Ajax code :

```js
function submitForm(){

    var server = 'http://localhost/test'; // Your PHP file
    var commentName = $('#commentName').val(); // The values of your form
    var commentMail = $('#commentMail').val(); // The values of your form
    var commentPhone = $('#commentPhone').val(); // The values of your form
    var comment = $('#comment').val(); // The values of your form

    $.ajax({ // Here the magic starts
        url: server+"/contact.php", // Where this function will send the values
        type:"POST", // To get the status of your php file
        data: "action=insertNews&commentName="+commentName+"&commentMail="+commentMail+"&commentPhone="+commentPhone+"&comment="+comment, // The values
        success: function (data){ // After sending the values to your php file you will receive number 1 or 2, if you receives number 1 it means sucess, but if you receives number 2 it means fail.
            if(data == '1'){    
                 alert("Is send");
            }
            else{
                alert("Oop");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Code PHP And HTML :

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$message = '';
$email = '';
$name ='';


$message = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$name = $_POST['phone'];

$to = "test@test.com";

$subject = 'New Message';

$message = " Le nom : ".$name."<br><br>".$message."<br><br> Email : ".$email;

$header = "$email";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
  echo '1';
}
else{
  echo '2';
}}
?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body onload="randNums()">
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
   <input id="commentName" onkeyup="validateName()" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"><label id="commentNamePrompt"></label><br>
   <input id="commentMail" onkeyup="validateMail()" name="mail" type="text" placeholder="Mail"><label id="commentMailPrompt"></label><br>
   <input id="commentPhone" onkeyup="validatePhone()" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone"><label id="commentPhonePrompt"></label><br>
   <textarea id="comment" onkeyup="validateComment()" name="commente" placeholder="Messege here"></textarea><label id="commentPrompt"></label><br> 
   <span id="digit1"></span> + 
   <span id="digit2"></span> = 
   <input id="captcha" size="2" onkeyup="validateCaptcha()"><label id="captchaPrompt"></label><br>
  </form>
 <button name="submit" onclick="validateCommentForm()" > Send</button><label id="commentFormPrompt"> </label>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to know is that's right ? and if I have a problem can you fixed ?

Comment: Is there a specific question here?

Comment: @larsAnders the problem is All thinks is right, but I always have a alert said " Ooops ", So, I ask professional persons to said to me is my code right and the problem is in the server or I have a problem in my code

Comment: First of all, mail function wouldn't work for localhost. secondly provide a valid email instead of `test@test.com`

Comment: @MahaDev So, the code is right ?

Comment: For the ajax, is it returning html or json format?

Comment: @Chay22 is it returning HTML

Comment: where is your contact.php page code

Comment: 1) `if(data == '1')` --> `if(data === '1')` your response is a string. 2) I'd better specify my `dataType` of response rather than let jquery to determine itself. 3) Don't stringify `data`, use something like answer below

Comment: @Ms.Nehal I make it, it's the second

Comment: @Chay22 Sorry, but I never work with Ajax, So, can you explain more specific to understand you ?

Comment: try changing this line`$header = $email;`, it was being treated as a string instead of variable. That's why mail are not sent

Comment: @sayou, is that the only issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert `die` after echo response :

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
  echo '1';
}
else{
  echo '2';
}
die;
}
```

and in ajax response, trim the data string you get :

```
if(data.trim() == "1"){
  alert("Is send");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use data sending in this format

```
 data:{action:'insertNews',commentName:commentName,commentMail:commentMail},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your php code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$phone= '';
$email = '';
$name ='';
$commente= $_POST['commente']; // not used anywhere

$name= $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['mail'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];

$to = "test@test.com";

$subject = 'New Message';

$message = " Le nom : ".$phone."<br><br>".$name."<br><br> Email : ".$email;

$header = $email;

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
  echo '1';
}
else{
  echo '2';
}}
?>
```

Comment: @sayou, you can check the my answer. Also let me know whether it solves your issue or not

Comment: don't work any other help ? I have problem in ajax code

Comment: @sayou wat exactly issue u r facing in ajax